# Unable prevent redirect to https

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-config

I have an apache2 with certbot. I need disable redirect form http to https for a single subdir html/tht.
I am develop an app with Mit app inventor and web component not support https, at this time.
So I need able html/tht to answer at http

I have read many other post and try to insert:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tht(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

in my config file sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf , but not success, test with curl and from http I receive error 301.
Also I try to write .htaccess file in /app.
It seem that any request go redirect to https first to execute rewrite.
I searched witch grep any config directive but found nothing.

Thank you for help me
Saverio

Comment: “I receive error 301” - the rule you’ve posted is a  302, not a 301. So if you are seeing a “301” then it’s likely something else is doing that. What other rules do you have in your config and .htaccess file(s).

Comment: This is in .htaccess in my subdir:

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] 
 
this is the curl answer: 

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
< Server: nginx 
< Date: Sun, 31 Dec 2023 13:37:04 GMT 
< Content-Type: text/html 
< Content-Length: 178 
< Connection: keep-alive 
< Location: https://***.***.***.it/ 
 
Also, why curl say Server: nginx ? 
I am sure that server is Apache2 
thank you

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77735688/edit) to add that additional information / code sample. Unformatted code in comments can be impossible to read, particularly since certain characters can be omitted due to the markdown formatting.